# Multiple gather() in dplyr without extending the length more than once

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a toy dataframe. I would like to gather multiple categories, but I should end up with only three `id`s. In other words, in the `id` column I should only have three repeats of the same number.

```
>a

id cat.a1  cat.a2 cat.a3 cat.b1  cat.b2 cat.b3 cat.c1  cat.c2 cat.c3 
1   1.0     2.0    3.0    1.0     2.0    3.0    1.0     2.0    3.0
2   1.0     2.0    3.0    1.0     2.0    3.0    1.0     2.0    3.0
3   1.0     2.0    3.0    1.0     2.0    3.0    1.0     2.0    3.0
```

The above data frame is what I am starting with. From there I was able to do the following

```
a %>% 
 gather(key1,cat.a,starts_with('cat.a')) %>%
 select(-starts_with('key')) %>% 
 arrange(id)
```

Which gives me

```
id   cat.a  cat.b1  cat.b2 cat.b3 cat.c1  cat.c2 cat.c3
1     1.0    1.0     2.0    3.0    1.0     2.0    3.0
1     2.0    1.0     2.0    3.0    1.0     2.0    3.0
1     3.0    1.0     2.0    3.0    1.0     2.0    3.0
2     1.0    1.0     2.0    3.0    1.0     2.0    3.0
2     2.0    1.0     2.0    3.0    1.0     2.0    3.0
2     3.0    1.0     2.0    3.0    1.0     2.0    3.0
3     1.0    1.0     2.0    3.0    1.0     2.0    3.0
3     2.0    1.0     2.0    3.0    1.0     2.0    3.0
3     3.0    1.0     2.0    3.0    1.0     2.0    3.0
```

How do I change my code to get

```
id  cat.a cat.b cat.c
1    1.0   2.0   3.0
1    1.0   2.0   3.0
1    1.0   2.0   3.0
2    1.0   2.0   3.0
2    1.0   2.0   3.0
2    1.0   2.0   3.0
3    1.0   2.0   3.0
3    1.0   2.0   3.0
3    1.0   2.0   3.0
```

So far I have tried doing multiple gathers, but as you may expect this has resulted in a much longer data frame than I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way with `tidyverse`,

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  gather(var, val, starts_with('cat')) %>% 
  group_by(var = sub('\\d+', '', var)) %>% 
  mutate(new = seq(n())) %>% 
  spread(var, val) %>% 
  select(-new) %>% 
  ungroup()

## A tibble: 9 × 4
#     id cat.a cat.b cat.c
#* <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     1     1
#2     1     2     2     2
#3     1     3     3     3
#4     2     1     1     1
#5     2     2     2     2
#6     2     3     3     3
#7     3     1     1     1
#8     3     2     2     2
#9     3     3     3     3
```

Comment: Could you explain what '\\d+' is doing? I know that it is regex, but I am not sure what is happening.

Comment: It removes the digits from a string. Try `sub('\\d+', '', 'abc12')`